# PSQLException: ERROR: could not open server file "path/photo.jpg" : No such file or directory

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, photo

how do i insert iod photo in Postgresql?! 
I have these photos in the server and i can't insert it with **lo_import** in Postgresql DB.

```
private static void insertPhoto(String nom,int pos) throws SQLException {
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();

    String path = "http://10.0.0.84/stade_photo/"+pos+".jpg";
    System.out.println(path);
    String sql = "UPDATE stadephenologique SET photo= "
            + "lo_import('"+path+"') WHERE nom='"+nom.replaceAll("'", "''")+"'";
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    stmt.close();
    connection.commit();
    System.out.println(nom );

}
```

this is the exception:

> Opened database successfully
>   http://10.0.0.84/stade_photo/1.jpg
>   Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not open server file "http://10.0.0.84/stade_photo/1.jpg": No such file or directory

Comment: `lo_import` can only access files that are stored on the server where Postgres is running. It cannot read files on remote computers and it cannot read files through the http protocol

Answer (score 0):

i have changed the type of photo to bytea and it's worked for me with this function

```
private static void insertPhoto(String nom,int pos) throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException {
    String path = "stade_photo/"+pos+".jpg";
    System.out.println(path+" nom="+nom);

    PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE stadephenologique SET photo = ? WHERE nom = ?");
    File file = new File(path);
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    try
    {
        pstmt.setBinaryStream(1, in, (int) file.length());
        pstmt.setString(2, nom);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        connection.commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception is:- " + ee);
    }
}
```